# Gurobi: Using addConstrs() but the expression is not right

Tags: python, c++, gurobi

I am new to Gurobi and Python. I am trying to solve a simple mixed binary problem, but there are some errors.

I defined the problem as follows,

I want variable u[1,1], u[2,1], u[3,1] and u[1,2], u[2,2], u[3,2], similarity to variable p. I want to add above constraints, but there are some errors saying my expressions is not right.

```py
u=m.addVars([1, 2, 3], [1, 2], vtype=GRB.BINARY)
p=m.addVars(3,2,lb=0.0)

m.addConstrs(p[i,j]<= 30*u[i,j]
            for i in range(3)
            for j in range(2))
m.addConstrs(p[(i,j)]>=5*u[(i,j)]
            for i in range(3)
            for j in range(2))
```

The error is like this

```
line 14, in <module>
    for i in range(3)
  File "model.pxi", line 3062, in gurobipy.Model.addConstrs
  File "/Users/Documents/pyexercise/HW4Q1.py", line 15, in <genexpr>
    for j in range(2))
KeyError: (0, 0)
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Python, using `range(n)` returns a list of `n` numbers from `0` to `n-1`. Thus, your `addConstrs()` functions iterate over the keys `(0,0)`, `(0,1)`, `(1,0)`, `(1,1)`, `(2,0)`, and `(2,1)`.

However, the `u` variables are indexed by `(1,1)`, `(1,2)`, `(2,1)`, `(2,2)`, `(3,1)`, and `(3,2)`:

```
gurobi> u = m.addVars([1, 2, 3], [1, 2], vtype=GRB.BINARY)
gurobi> u.keys()
<gurobi.tuplelist (6 tuples, 2 values each):
 ( 1 , 1 )
 ( 1 , 2 )
 ( 2 , 1 )
 ( 2 , 2 )
 ( 3 , 1 )
 ( 3 , 2 )
>
```

You receive a `KeyError` because the indices of the constraints do not match the indices of the variables. To fix this, you can change the construction of the `u` variables to match that of the `p` variables:

```
gurobi> u = m.addVars(3, 2, vtype=GRB.BINARY)
gurobi> u.keys()
<gurobi.tuplelist (6 tuples, 2 values each):
 ( 0 , 0 )
 ( 0 , 1 )
 ( 1 , 0 )
 ( 1 , 1 )
 ( 2 , 0 )
 ( 2 , 1 )
>
```